# XSD: Using Mutually Exclusive Tags

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am writing an .xsd file and have a section in the .xml similar to the following

```
<time start="2006-10-02T09:15:26.43Z" />
```

-OR-

```
<time end="2006-10-02T09:15:26.43Z" />
```

My initial research has led me to use the  tags in XSD, like so

```
<xs:element name="time">
     <xs:complexType>
          <xs:choice>
               <xs:element name="start">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                         <xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime">
                              <xs:pattern value=".*Z" />
                         </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
               </xs:element>
               <xs:element name="end">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                         <xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime">
                              <xs:pattern value=".*Z" />
                         </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
               </xs:element>
          </xs:choice>
     </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

When I check my XSD against a known good, I get the error that "Attribute 'start' is not allowed to appear in element 'time'.

Any idea where I went wrong?

Edit: Apparently it matters that I am using 1.0 since that would mean I have no access to assert.

Answer (score 0):

In your instance document, `start` and `end` are attributes, but you have declared them in the schema as elements. They need to be declared using `xs:attribute`.

In XSD 1.0 you can declare two optional attributes but you cannot declare that they are mutually exclusive. For that you need XSD 1.1 and `xs:assert`.